# Halcon - detect bright spots compared to local surroundings

Tags: brightness, halcon

I'd need to detect bright regions in the image. Would be quite easy with threshold. But I need to get spots that are bright compared to its surroundings, not based on an absolute value.

What would be a good way to do this?

Unfortunately I do not have sample images at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background does not have too much texture, you can try the 'local_threshold' operator.

There is a nice example of it included with HDevelop demonstrating the operator for OCR purposes.